# Wicket search form using loadable detachable model, null pointer

Tags: forms, search, wicket

so a little about the project: basically been trying to get a search function working to update a listview which I have done before and had no problem; until now.
I cannot seem to find the issue, here is hoping you guys and girls can!

I get a null pointer issue when running:

```
modelList.setObject(exerciseJdbc.fetchExercisesByAttr(3,
                    exercise.getName(), null, exercise.getComplexity()
                            .getLevel()));
```

Now I am sure this is a simple mistake but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

```
public class ManageExercise extends BaseManagerPage {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3241765837700606142L;

private ModalWindow mwAddExercise;


private LoadableDetachableModel<List<Exercise>> modelList;

@SpringBean
ExerciseJdbc exerciseJdbc;

public ManageExercise() {
    final Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
    add(mwAddExercise = new ModalWindow("mwAddExercise"));

    final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("wmc");
    wmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    try{
    modelList = exerciseModel();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Form<Exercise> searchForm = new Form<Exercise>("searchForm", new CompoundPropertyModel<Exercise>(exercise));
    searchForm.add(new TextField<Integer>("searchId", new PropertyModel<Integer>(exercise, "id")));
    searchForm.add(new TextField<String>("searchName", new PropertyModel<String>(exercise, "name")));   
    // searchForm.add(new DropDownChoice<String>("complexity.level",
    // new PropertyModel<String>(this, "complexity")));
    searchForm.add(new AjaxLink<String>("searchSubmit") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            modelList.setObject(exerciseJdbc.fetchExercisesByAttr(exercise.getId(), exercise.getName(), null, exercise.getComplexity().getLevel()));
            target.add(wmc);
        }

    });



    add(searchForm);

    ListView<Exercise> lvExercise = new ListView<Exercise>("lvExercise",
            modelList) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Exercise> item) {
            final Exercise model = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("id", Integer.toString(model.getId())));
            item.add(new Label("name", model.getName()));
            item.add(new ExternalLink("demoUrl", model.getDemoUrl(), model
                    .getDemoUrl()));
            item.add(new Label("complexity", model.getComplexity()
                    .getLevel()));
            item.add(new AjaxLink<String>("edit") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    renderAddExercise(item.getModelObject());
                    mwAddExercise.show(target);
                }
            });
            item.add(new AjaxLink<String>("delete") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    exerciseJdbc.disableExercise(model);
                    target.add(wmc);

                }
            });
        }
    };

    wmc.add(lvExercise);
    add(wmc);

    mwAddExercise.setWindowClosedCallback(new WindowClosedCallback() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(wmc);
        }
    });

    AjaxLink<String> addExercise = new AjaxLink<String>("addExercise") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            renderAddExercise(new Exercise());
            mwAddExercise.show(target);

        }

    };

    add(addExercise);

}

private LoadableDetachableModel<List<Exercise>> exerciseModel() {
    LoadableDetachableModel<List<Exercise>> exercideModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<Exercise>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected List<Exercise> load() {
            return exerciseJdbc.fetchAllExercises();
        }
    };
    return exercideModel;
}

private void renderAddExercise(Exercise exercise) {
    mwAddExercise.setContent(new AddExercisePanel(mwAddExercise
            .getContentId(), exercise, mwAddExercise));
}
```

}

Let me know if I have missed out any information required but I have a horrible feeling it is some kind of very stupid mistake.

Comment: what is the object that is null? modelList, exerciseJdbc or exercise?

Comment: exercises attributes, it appears that the property model i assigned to the textfields are incorrect

Comment: it seems that you dont set the property for complexity, looking at your code the 'exercise' shouldn't be null... but the exercise.getComplexity() might returnull, try to uncomment to code above it where you add the DropDownChoice to the searchForm

Comment: Ahh ok to clarify the object itself is instantiated but the attributes are null, the complexity will return null and that is expected however name and id should not be returning null if a user has entered data into the text fields for which a property model is assigned

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an `AjaxLink` for the searchSubmit, so the value of the `TextFields` aren't submitted to the server.

There are two options to solve this problem:

- Get rid of the `AjaxLink` and use a form submit solution

or

- Add an Ajax behavior to the `TextField` like the code below:

> //ajax onblur behavior
>       searchForm.add(new TextField("searchId", new PropertyModel(exercise, "id")).add(new
>   AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onblur") {
>
> ```
>                   @Override
>                   protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
>                       //should have the id here
>                       exercise.getId();   
>                   }
>                 }
>               ));
> ```

Comment: What are your views on the AjaxSubmitLink, would that be sufficiant ?

Comment: I never used it, but I dont think it will work... test and let me know :)

Comment: you are correct in that AjaxSubmitLink does not act as i expected it to. I am still very confused as to why my model is not being updated as soon I hit the submit link though. The documentation says it forces a submit on the target form you pass to in your constructor but this does not seem to happen.

Comment: change it to a submit button, and check in the onSubmit form if your model is updated... if yes, you can assume it is because of the ajax. Did you try to use my suggestion with the ajax behavior for the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this was in retrospect rather simple:

I replaced my AjaxLink with an AjaxSubmitLink, placed this link outside of the form and passed the form through to the link as a constructor.

In the OnSubmit method I called detatch on the model and then setObject; passing through a call to fetch new data from the db.

This works perfectly, hope this helps anyone in a similar situation, add to this if any questions arise.